# Remove multiple spaces but leave single space in R

Tags: r, gsub, spacing

I have text like below.

```
"The comm   unity is here to help you wi   th specific co   ding"
```

And I want to remove triple spaces in the sentence while leaving single space.

I tried

```
gsub(text, "   ", "")
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove exactly three spaces *inside* a word use:

```r
x <- "The comm   unity is here to help you wi   th specific co   ding"
output <- gsub("\\b[ ]{3}\\b", "", x)
output

[1] "The community is here to help you with specific coding"
```

Comment: Sorry. I realized there is something wrong with the example sentence so I changed it.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work, removing more than a single space:

```
st <- "The comm   unity is here to help you wi   th specific co   ding"
st
[1] "The comm   unity is here to help you wi   th specific co   ding"
gsub('\\s{2,}','',st)
[1] "The community is here to help you with specific coding"
```